# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.manoj.util.PRNGFixes$LinuxPRNGSecureRandomProvider

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio and getting this exception when run application at 4.2 version and when I'm running at s4 then it's running successfully.

Please anyone can suggest me cause of this!!!

```
7356-7356/com.manoj E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.manoj.util.PRNGFixes$LinuxPRNGSecureRandomProvider
            at com.manoj.util.PRNGFixes.installLinuxPRNGSecureRandom(PRNGFixes.java:101)
            at com.manoj.util.PRNGFixes.apply(PRNGFixes.java:46)
            at com.manoj.app.ImApp.onCreate(ImApp.java:253)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4592)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are all the required/dependant jars bundled into a single runnable jar ?

Comment: check this [link](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)